# JSON format for rest request

Tags: json, rest

I am trying to save list of objects/details (say my detail is MWLAppMenuConfigDetail) via POST rest API. 
My rest code is :

```
 public Detail saveMenu(MWLAppMenuConfigDetail[] mwlAppMenuConfigJAXObject)
    {
    ArrayList<MWLAppMenuConfigDetail> mwlAppDetail = new ArrayList<MWLAppMenuConfigDetail>();
    for(int i=0; i <mwlAppMenuConfigJAXObject.length;i++)
    mwlAppDetail.add(mwlAppMenuConfigJAXObject[i]);
    }
```

and my JSON is:

```
 [{"appId":"appmn000000000000003","menuId":"appmn000000000000000","render":"1","customImageId":"image000000000001025","authToken":"KfP1yfxgv0R2ZKOgB8ei","insertMode":"true"},{"appId":"appmn000000000000003","menuId":"appmn000000000000001","render":"1","customImageId":"image000000000001025","authToken":"KfP1yfxgv0R2ZKOgB8ei","insertMode":"true"},{"appId":"appmn000000000000003","menuId":"appmn000000000000002","render":"0","customImageId":"image000000000001025","authToken":"KfP1yfxgv0R2ZKOgB8ei","insertMode":"true"},{"appId":"appmn000000000000003","menuId":"appmn000000000000003","render":"0","customImageId":"image000000000001025","authToken":"KfP1yfxgv0R2ZKOgB8ei","insertMode":"true"}]
```

I also tried :

```
{"MWLAppMenuConfigDetail":[{"appId":"appmn000000000000003","menuId":"appmn000000000000000","render":"1","customImageId":"image000000000001025","authToken":"KfP1yfxgv0R2ZKOgB8ei","insertMode":"true"},{"appId":"appmn000000000000003","menuId":"appmn000000000000001","render":"1","customImageId":"image000000000001025","authToken":"KfP1yfxgv0R2ZKOgB8ei","insertMode":"true"},{"appId":"appmn000000000000003","menuId":"appmn000000000000002","render":"0","customImageId":"image000000000001025","authToken":"KfP1yfxgv0R2ZKOgB8ei","insertMode":"true"},{"appId":"appmn000000000000003","menuId":"appmn000000000000003","render":"0","customImageId":"image000000000001025","authToken":"KfP1yfxgv0R2ZKOgB8ei","insertMode":"true"}]}.
```

My request doesn't goes into rest function.
for testing when I removed the JSON from input data and changed function as:

```
public Detail saveMenu()
{
//body
}
```

It works, so I am sure that the parameter definition of rest function and JSON input data is not compatible. Please help.

Comment: Where's formation of Detail object?

Comment: Formation of detail object means? on rest API side or on requesting json side ?

Comment: `@POST
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 @Path("save")
 public Detail saveMenu(MWLAppMenuConfigDetail[] mwlAppMenuConfigJAXObject){}`

Comment: no no in your saveMenu method..

Comment: it converts by itself. using JAXBElement. I have similar code working for xml input making it to work for JSON as well. in xml I pass <MWLAppMenuConfigDetails><MWLAppMenuConfigDetail></MWLAppMenuConfigDetail></MWLAppMenuConfigDetails>.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh my Bad. ENtry for this detail(object) was missing in JAXBContextResolver . We need to make an entry if array of object will be accepted as input.